# How to Sync user data from multiple sources BDC and AD?

Tags: 2013, bcs, forefront, fim

I have a user profile that has fields from multiple sources. fields form AD and fields from BCS -> SQL DB. Everything is working, except if the DB is down, the fields get populated with empty data. However this is not the behavior I am looking for, I want to sync and if one of the sources is down, the current data is shown and not empty fields. I have been banging my head against the wall to this to work, in FIM and I can get one thing working or the other... it either updates or it does not update any changes if I disable Allow Null (from configure attribute flow).

How can I do this?

EDIT: My setup-up is similar to: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/momalek/archive/2011/02/06/sharepoint-2010-user-profile-service-part-4-configure-ups-synchronization-sources.aspx#comments

A Filter in the syncronization, some sort of rule? I am a bit lost

Comment: Could you post some more detail regarding the environment? How did you set up the connection, etc in the profile?

Comment: Sure the data is populated by a sync process, the sync process calls a BDC object that has a ReadItem(id) that updates the fields. The problems that i am having is detecting that the database is not accessible, and when it's not accessible to stop the overwrite of the fields. Ill post a screenshot of the process tomorrow, it's in a VM. i believe this can be fixed in the FIM Join or something like that, because I have not found a way using code to do this...

Comment: Always is possible to create a BDC in .Net as a wrapper to sql server.  However, it requires to know how to program it and the whole operation is not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround -- configure the UP sync process to be disabled. Then write a process to check the remote source. If the source is available, enable the UP sync.

Comment: hum yeah, not sure how I would do that. I have 4 days experience with sp